# Block signature attachments in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, attachments

Of many customers I get a signature in the form of an image as attachment.

I only need this attachment once, but now all emails of that customers are marked as "with attachment".

How could I block those attachments? Or blacklist them? But keep all other attachments, that are not in my blacklist?

Comment: I would write or find an Thunderbird add-on to do this.

Comment: I cannot find any addon that does this. would it be easy to program such? I also asked this in this [german thunderbird forum](http://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=63260)

Comment: Have you found one?

Comment: none yet. I hope there will be a solution one day